# Connect SQL Server to Jupyter Python Notebook

Tags: python, sql-server, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc

I am trying to connect my SQL Server database to Jupyter Python notebook, but getting errors which are either Driver related or access related:

[Jupyter to SQL connect error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXYk3.png)

The SQL Server is hosted on a Virtual Machine and I use "Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA" as authentication method to connect to the same via MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Error Message:

> Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open server "" requested by the login.  The login failed. (40532) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open server "" requested by the login.  The login failed. (40532)')

Can anyone please help me debug this or suggest any alternative approach to accomplish the same.

Comment: Aside... avoid SQL Server Native Client 11.0, it hasn't been updated since SQL Server 2012 days and will receive no new features. Consider upgrading to a current and supported version of ODBC Driver nnn for SQL Server on [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server), [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) or [macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos).

Comment: Client-side login failure messages are intentionally vague (for security reasons). Have you checked the Error Logs on the SQL Server instance? If you have access to the SQL Server instance via SSMS, DBeaver, etc., then look for Error 18456 messages in the Error Log, take note of the `State` number there and compare it against the `State` numbers listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the actual cause of the login problem.